# Arduino printing Integer instead of string

Tags: java, android, terminal, bluetooth, arduino

I have a problem, which I have been working on for some time. I have an Arduino Uno board and an HC-05 Bluetooth transceiver with TTL outputs.

The connections are as follows:

```
HC-05             Arduino UNO
-----             -----------
RX       -->      Pin 11
TX       -->      Pin 10
+5v      -->      +5v
GND      -->      GND
```

The code is as follows:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(10, 11); // RX | TX
String character;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(10, INPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
  Serial.println("Enter AT commands:");
  BTSerial.begin(38400);  // HC-05 default speed in AT command more
  BTSerial.println("Welcome to ARBA-Beat");
}

void loop() {
  // Keep reading from HC-05 and send to Arduino Serial Monitor
  if (BTSerial.available()) {
    character = BTSerial.read();
    Serial.println(character);
    //BTSerial.write(character);
    BTSerial.flush();
  }
}
```

I use [Bluetooth terminal app for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ptah.apps.bluetoothterminal&hl=en) to transmit messages to the Arduino.

The problem is I am getting integer numbers instead of a string.

> **String: Arduino is great**

[image]

I have no idea what's happeninng.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Use char as character type instead of String and Serial.write() that.

Comment: @ctrl-d I tried the solution you suggested. Now i am getting garbage values (something like this -->  ⸮⸮⸮)

Comment: Do you see the "Welcome to ARBA-Beat"?

Comment: @ctrl-d yes, it shows

Comment: If you enable //BTSerial.write(character); does it show your input?

Comment: @ctrl-d no, it doesn't

Comment: You should connect pin 10 and 11 on the arduino, to test btserial alone. You should see the welcome message.

Comment: Why are you calling flush() on BTSerial when you haven't tried to send anything over BTSerial?  Do you know what flush() does?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `String` and use a `char` type.

```
char c= BTSerial.read();
Serial.write(c); Serial.write('\n');
```